# Developer Console throws Type Exception

Tags: visualforce-component, developer-console, polymorphism, typecast

I have a base class that's a mash up of the base classes [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Controller_Component_Communication). What's important is that this class contains the following property and method:

```
public CommunicationBase Owner { get; set; }
public CommunicationBase getThis() { return this; }
```

Now I've got a page and a component that both derive this class. In the component I have an attribute:

```
<apex:attribute name="controller" type="CommunicationBase" assignTo="{!Owner}" />
```

And the page uses that controller:

```
<c:GenericLookup controller="{!this}" />
```

Kosher, right? Wrong. The Developer Console throws this error:

[image]
What's even more bizarre is if I pass a string property I get no complaints.

What's going on? More importantly: How can I get things to work?

---

**Update** As requested, the classes in question:

I've opted for the multiple component approach, and I've merged the page and component bases so I can (if I wanted) get a chain reaction going.

```
public with sharing virtual class CommunicationBase {
    /// Owner section
    private Map<String, CommunicationBase> componentControllerMap = new Map<String, CommunicationBase>();
    public virtual Map<String, CommunicationBase> getComponentControllerMap() { return componentControllerMap; }
    public virtual CommunicationBase getComponentController(String key) { return componentControllerMap.get(key); }
    public virtual void setComponentController(String key, CommunicationBase child) { componentControllerMap.put(key, child); }
    public CommunicationBase getThis() { return this; }

    /// Ownee section
    public String Key {
        get;
        set {
            if (value != null) {
                Key = value;
                if (Owner != null) Owner.setComponentController(Key, this);
            }
        }
    }
    public CommunicationBase Owner {
        get;
        set {
            if (value != null) {
                Owner = value;
                if (Key != null) Owner.setComponentController(Key, this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the component controller:

```
public class GenericLookup extends CommunicationBase {

    public String Name { get; set; }

    private SObject sub;
    public SObject Record {
        get {
            if (sub == null) {
                if (NewID != null) sub = Database.query('SELECT ID, Name FROM ' + LookupType + 'WHERE ID = ' + NewID);
                else if (LookupType != null) sub = (SObject)Type.forName(LookupType).newInstance();
            }
            return sub;
        }
        set { if ((sub = value) != null) NewID = sub.ID; }
    }

    public ID OldID { get; set; }
    public ID NewID { get; set; }

    private Boolean mod = false;
    public String Modified {
        get { return mod ? '1' : '0'; }
        set { mod = '1'.equals(value); }
    }

    public String LookupType {
        get;
        set {
            SObject temp = (SObject)Type.forName(value).newInstance();
            LookupType = value;
            if (Record == null) Record = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the page controller:

```
public with sharing class Manage_Contact_Relations extends CommunicationBase {

    public List<Schema.PicklistEntry> RelationshipTypes {
        get { return Contact_Relationships__c.Relationship_Type__c.getDescribe().getPicklistValues(); }
    }

    public final Account ParentGroup { get; private set; }
    public final List<Account> SubGroups { get; private set; }
    public final List<Contact_Relationships__c> ContactRelationships { get; private set; }
    public final Set<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    public final Account DummyAccount { get; private set; }
    public Contact SelectedContact {
        get { return DummyAccount.Agent_Broker__r; }
        set { DummyAccount.Agent_Broker__r = value; }
    }
    public Contact AdditionalContact {
        get {
            GenericLookup gl = (GenericLookup)super.getComponentController('AdditionalContact');
            return (Contact)gl.Record;
        }
        set {
            GenericLookup gl = (GenericLookup)super.getComponentController('AdditionalContact');
            gl.Record = value;
        }
    }
    public string ReturnURL { get; set; }

    public Manage_Contact_Relations() {
        AdditionalContact = new Contact();
        DummyAccount = new Account();

        List<Account> accounts =
            [SELECT ID, Name, ParentID
             FROM Account
             WHERE ID = :apexpages.currentpage().getParameters().get('AccountId')
             OR ParentID = :apexpages.currentpage().getParameters().get('AccountId')];

        SubGroups = new List<Account>();
        for (Account a: accounts) {
            if (a.ParentID == null) ParentGroup = a;
            else SubGroups.add(a);
        }

        ContactRelationships =
            [SELECT
             ID,
             Related_Account__c,
             Related_Contact__c,
             Relationship_Type__c
             FROM Contact_Relationships__c
             WHERE Related_Account__c IN :accounts];

        Set<ID> IDs = new Set<ID>();
        for (Contact_Relationships__c cr: ContactRelationships) IDs.add(cr.Related_Contact__c);

        Contacts = new Set<Contact>(
            [SELECT ID, Name
             FROM Contact
             WHERE ID IN :IDs]);
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getSelectableContacts() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        for (Contact c: Contacts) options.add(new SelectOption(c.ID, c.Name));
        return options;
    }

    public PageReference AddContact() {
        ApexPages.Message info = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, String.valueOf(AdditionalContact != null));
        ApexPages.addMessage(info);
        if (AdditionalContact != null) {
            SelectedContact = AdditionalContact;
            AdditionalContact = null;
        }
        else {
            ApexPages.Message error = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Select a contact to add');
            ApexPages.addMessage(error);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

You've already got the snippet from the Visualforce page.

---

**Update**: The attributes on the component:

```
<apex:attribute name="uniqueKey" type="String" required="true" assignTo="{!Key}" description="The key given to this component so the page can easily get access to it" />
<apex:attribute name="controller" type="CommunicationBase" assignTo="{!Owner}" required="true" description="The page controller" />
<apex:attribute name="type" type="String" required="true" assignTo="{!LookupType}" description="The class of SObject this lookup will operate on. E.g. Contact" />
<apex:attribute name="fieldDisplayName" type="String" description="Object's display name field" default="Name" assignTo="{!Name}" />
```

And the actual tag for including it

```
<c:GenericLookup uniqueKey="AdditionalContact" controller="{!this}" type="Contact" />
```

Comment: From looking at the reference you've cited, there could easily be much more going on. Those are virtual classes that need to be extended. If you've not extended them properly, the Type may not be correct. Please provide the code for your complete classes. Have you tried to run these tests from Eclipse? The Developer Console isn't the most robust for this type of development.

Comment: @crmprogdev I've added my controllers, so please let me know if you spot anything. I haven't tried Eclipse. We've had some trouble setting it up at my work--not Eclipse, but connecting it to Salesforce--but with this downtime I'm thinking I'll try to set it up.

Comment: Perhaps it will work better if you write a top level `interface` that all these classes share and use that as the type you accept in your controller.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Do you really think that will solve the problem? The only difference I see is that every class implementing the interface has to implement those methods or there'd be something like `CommunicationBase` that implements it in which case that's more cluttered than my current solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally**, found this [Q&A](http://developer.chatter7bk.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000098eKIAQ). Having an attribute named controller is apparently a *very* bad idea. I've renamed it to parentController (and `Owner` to `Parent` for consistency) and things seem to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

See the section of the page you referenced titled **"Extended to support multiple visual force(vf) components on a vf page by Kunle Adeniy"**. In that section, all the methods were modified to use hashes and maps which is what allowed strings to passed when more than one controller of different types were used on the same page.

Your page controller really isn't an extension of the virtual class. Instead, it's what I think of as a custom controller that also calls an extension of that virtual class. I.E., its much more than an extension. For that reason, its my opinion that you need to make similar modifications to your controller code as referenced in the section I mentioned above.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is supposed to help. I'll update my question with the actual attribute(s) and component tag. I had simplified things for the question, but then you wanted more and the details don't match the original simplification, and that's where I think you're seeing something that I already handled.

Comment: I just took a closer look at your code and the virtual class. What I particularly noticed is that `private Map<String, CommunicationBase> componentControllerMap` appears to be what `getThis()` is referring to or creates if an Owner is passed to it so it can get or assign a key. From reading your code, it looks like an Owner is a (page reference) controller, not a user. @AdrianLarson may be on target with his suggestion to implement as an interface.

Comment: Like I asked Adrian: Can you explain why making it an interface will solve the problem? And correct me if I'm wrong, but the `this` keyword refers to the instance of the class (in this case, `CommunicationBase`), not a field in the class.

Comment: Yes, it does refer to an instance of `CommunicationBase` and that may be exactly the reason you're having the problem you are! The compiler may be interpreting this line `<apex:attribute name="controller" type="CommunicationBase" assignTo="{!Owner}"` as referring to an `Id` instead of a `String` since the keyword `Owner` would refer to an `Id`! Change your class to use something else and that may solve your issue.

Comment: So is it assuming CommunicationBase is an SObject? Because CommunicationBase is a custom class, not a custom object, so it doesn't come with an `ID` as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Owner isn't an Object, instead it's a polymorphic relationship identifier that usually refers to the User Object. But something along the lines of what you've said is essentially what I'm thinking is happening. It would definitely explain why it's rejecting a string. Regardless, it thinks it should be looking for an ID because of the polymorphic relationship associated with Owner. I'm at the limit of my knowledge in this area and out of ideas